# Is there a permalink to the latest Joomla version?

Tags: cms, download

Is there a permalink which can be used to download the latest Joomla version?

For example, Wordpress allows you to download the latest version at:

`https://wordpress.org/latest.zip`

I [asked this on WM.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54971/is-there-a-permalink-to-the-latest-version-of-joomla-zip-archive) a while back and was told no, but now we have our own community maybe someone may know (or know how to make this happen!). My use-case is to include it within our cPanel package system so I can automate the 'new site' process, but I can see it being handy for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no permanent link to the latest version of joomla as far as I know.

Joomla has opted for links with the file name. Example for joomla 3.2.3 :

```
http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/19239/158104/Joomla_3.2.3-Stable-Full_Package.zip
```

You can find the latest version of joomla here though : http://www.joomla.org/download.html

And you can suscribe to the [rss feed](http://feeds.joomla.org/JoomlaSecurityNews) to be aware of new updates.

Comment: I understand the usage of the full version name in the filename. Just would be nice to have a symlink-y type deal to quickly get the latest without having to parse RSS feeds or XML docs.

Comment: Currently there is no such link, but we are figuring out how to move the packages away from JoomlaCode and it may well be that there will be such a link then. But that's future and wishful thinking :)

Comment: Does anyone know the approach WP takes? Could it be easily duplicated?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

You have to parse the last node of each xml file you will get the link to download latest version.

Joomla Using this method to shows  New version of Joomla is available! on admin panel

For Long Term Support (LTS) branch -( Recommended) Stable release

```
http://update.joomla.org/core/list.xml
```

Short term support (STS) branch

```
http://update.joomla.org/core/sts/list_sts.xml
```

Testing versions.

```
http://update.joomla.org/core/test/list_test.xml
```

All these XML files have link to their details zip files.

Hope it helps..